# Passing argument in Promise.prototype.then()

Tags: javascript, promise

While going through a topic on MDN Web Docs I came across an example

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

```js
var promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('Success!');
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // expected output: "Success!"
});
```

I am a beginner in JS and my doubt is regarding the argument being passed in the function inside the `promise1.then()`

We earlier passed the string 'Success!' in the `resolve()` method. But we did not specify before-hand what data we are assigning to the `value` variable (which is being passed in the `console.log()` ). Intuitively, shouldn't we have explicitly defined `var value = /* Data from Promise.resolve() */` for first defining what the data `value` carries and subsequently passing it in `console.log()`?

Otherwise, I can just change the name `value` to anything, say, `myVar` and get away with the same result: logging "Success!" to the console.

I tried Googling it but it wasn't helpful as I do not know what topic of JS my question pertains to. So, please do suggest relevant material. Thanks!

Comment: `I can just change the name value to anything, say, myVar and get away with the same result` Yep. It's just an argument - you can name it whatever you want and get the same output. (that's what minifiers do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We earlier passed the string 'Success!' in the resolve() method. But we did not specify before-hand what data we are assigning to the value variable (which is being passed in the console.log() ).

The value that is passed to a function argument is determined **when you call** the function.

The code that calls it is part of the Promise library (i.e. written by someone else). They specified what it should be.

> Intuitively, shouldn't we have explicitly defined var value = /* Data from Promise.resolve() */

No. The people who wrote the Promise library already did that.

> Otherwise, I can just change the name value to anything

Yes. The names of arguments don't determine the values of what is passed into them. The positions do.

Comment: Okay. So can I see the code that is written in that library?

Comment: @SunitGautam — Depends on the library. Should be fairly easy to find if you are using a stand-alone Promise library like Bluebird, harder if you are using the native one built into Firefox (because Firefox has a lot of source code) and probably impossible if you are using the native one built into Edge (which isn't, AFAIK, open source).

Answer (score 0):

`value` is just a name you gave the first argument to the `.then()` handler callback function.  You can name it anything you want.  Whatever name you give it, it will get the value of the first argument to the `.then()` handler.  That's true for all functions.  You can name the arguments whatever you want and it does not change what value they get when they are called.

> Otherwise, I can just change the name value to anything, say, myVar and get away with the same result: logging "Success!" to the console.

Yes, you can make the name of the argument anything you want.  Whatever name you give it, it will receive the first argument from when the function is called.  It is the caller who determines what value the argument will have.  It is the function declaration that determines what name that first argument will have inside the function so that you can refer to that first function argument.

In this case, the function is called by the internals of the promise library and when it calls the `.then()` callback function, it passes as the first argument the resolved value of the promise which your case is your `"Success!"` string.